# Assembly Code from C program

Tags: c, assembly

I have a C program which has a function decod and the function has the following statements.

My `decode.c` script:

```
int decod(int x, int y, int z) {
   int ty = y;
   ty = ty - z;
   int py = ty;
   py = py << 31;
   py = py >> 31;
   ty = ty * x;
   py = py ^ ty;
   }
```

The assembly code of this program (generated by `gcc -S decod.c`) shows the following code.

```
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
movl    %edx, -28(%rbp)
movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
subl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
sall    $31, -4(%rbp)
sarl    $31, -4(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
imull   -20(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
xorl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
```

But, I want the program generate an assembly file with only the following lines of code.

```
subl    %edx, %esi
movl    %esi, %eax
sall    $31, %eax
sarl    $31, %eax
imull   %edi, %esi
xorl    %esi, %eax
ret
```

I know I am pretty close to write a program which will generate the above mentioned code. But, I am clueless why the script generates different assembly code. Any direction will be helpful.

Comment: That function does not return anything..

Comment: If you want it to result in *that* code, why are you writing it in C instead of assembly?

Comment: to get sensible asm-code, turn on optimization. On the other hand, to have sensible optimized code, provide code that will not be optimize out completely, ( since it doesnt return anything, it is completely useless)

Comment: If you want the compiler to optimize the code, you have to [Ask for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778538/how-many-gcc-optimization-levels-are-there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile your function as is, in optimization level3, `-O3` the entire function is optimized out. This is because there is no return value and `py` and `ty` are anyways discarded after the function.

For reference the code is below

```
    .globl  decod
    .def    decod;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   decod
decod:
    .seh_endprologue
    ret
    .seh_endproc
```

If however, you add a `return py;` at the end the code generated is as follows.

```
    .globl  decod
    .def    decod;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   decod
decod:
    .seh_endprologue
    subl    %r8d, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    imull   %edx, %ecx
    sall    $31, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    xorl    %ecx, %eax
    ret
    .seh_endproc
```

This is functionally identical to what you are expecting.